# Android Studio stops recommending in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Android studio just stops recommending in XML since i add `mavenCentral()` in my Gradle. I can't live without it because it's making my life easy.

Comment: Which Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: The latest one.

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: Yes, too many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. gradle sync
2. File -> Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: I also deleted .idea folder 3 times.

Comment: Have you added google() and jcenter() to the repositories as well? It all sounds really weird and I'm trying to come up with at least something